# Difficulty updating matplotlib on Mac OS

Tags: python, matplotlib, pip

EDIT: Fixed. Solved by installing `anaconda` and running python through that.

I'm running Sierra 10.12.5 on my Mac, and `pip list | grep matplotlib` shows that I'm running matplotlib (1.3.1). I am trying to update matplotlib to 2.0.2 (the latest version), but any `sudo pip install matplotlib --upgrade` seems to fail with a very very long error (won't paste it all here) that gets to:

```
Terrys-MBP:Bitcore-master-2 Terry$ pip install matplotlib --upgrade
Downloading/unpacking matplotlib from https://pypi.python.org/packages/f5/f0/9da3ef24ea7eb0ccd12430a261b66eca36b924aeef06e17147f9f9d7d310/matplotlib-2.0.2.tar.gz#md5=061111784278bde89b5d4987014be4ca
Downloading matplotlib-2.0.2.tar.gz (53.9MB): 53.9MB downloaded
Running setup.py      (path:/private/var/folders/m5/1fg5rnj11_9cz5pntlqlwzyc0000gn/T/pip_build_Terry/matplotlib/setup.py) egg_info for package matplotlib
============================================================================
Edit setup.cfg to change the build options

BUILDING MATPLOTLIB
            matplotlib: yes [2.0.2]
                python: yes [2.7.10 (default, Feb  7 2017, 00:08:15)  [GCC
                        4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.34)]]
              platform: yes [darwin]

REQUIRED DEPENDENCIES AND EXTENSIONS
                 numpy: yes [version 1.13.0]
                   six: yes [using six version 1.10.0]
              dateutil: yes [using dateutil version 2.6.0]
           functools32: yes [using functools32]
          subprocess32: yes [using subprocess32]
                  pytz: yes [using pytz version 2017.2]
                cycler: yes [using cycler version 0.10.0]
               tornado: yes [using tornado version 4.5.1]
             pyparsing: yes [using pyparsing version 2.2.0]
                libagg: yes [pkg-config information for 'libagg' could not
                        be found. Using local copy.]
              freetype: yes [version 2.8.0]
                   png: yes [version 1.6.29]
                 qhull: yes [pkg-config information for 'qhull' could not be
                        found. Using local copy.]

OPTIONAL SUBPACKAGES
           sample_data: yes [installing]
              toolkits: yes [installing]
                 tests: no  [skipping due to configuration]
        toolkits_tests: no  [skipping due to configuration]

OPTIONAL BACKEND EXTENSIONS
                macosx: yes [installing, darwin]
                qt5agg: no  [PyQt5 not found]
                qt4agg: no  [PySide not found; PyQt4 not found]
               gtk3agg: no  [Requires pygobject to be installed.]
             gtk3cairo: no  [Requires cairocffi or pycairo to be installed.]
                gtkagg: no  [Requires pygtk]
                 tkagg: yes [installing; run-time loading from Python Tcl /
                        Tk]
                 wxagg: no  [requires wxPython]
                   gtk: no  [Requires pygtk]
                   agg: yes [installing]
                 cairo: no  [cairocffi or pycairo not found]
             windowing: no  [Microsoft Windows only]

OPTIONAL LATEX DEPENDENCIES
                dvipng: yes [version 1.15]
           ghostscript: yes [version 9.16]
                 latex: yes [version 3.14159265]
               pdftops: no

OPTIONAL PACKAGE DATA
                  dlls: no  [skipping due to configuration]

Requirement already up-to-date: numpy>=1.7.1 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from matplotlib)
Requirement already up-to-date: six>=1.10 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from matplotlib)
Requirement already up-to-date: python-dateutil in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from matplotlib)
Requirement already up-to-date: functools32 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from matplotlib)
Requirement already up-to-date: subprocess32 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from matplotlib)
Requirement already up-to-date: pytz in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from matplotlib)
Requirement already up-to-date: cycler>=0.10 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from matplotlib)
Requirement already up-to-date: pyparsing>=1.5.6,!=2.0.4,!=2.1.2,!=2.1.6 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from matplotlib)
Installing collected packages: matplotlib
Found existing installation: matplotlib 1.3.1
Uninstalling matplotlib:
Cleaning up...
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in main
status = self.run(options, args)
```

I assume there is something wrong with attempting to uninstall 1.3.1 because when I try to do a `pip uninstall` for my matplotlib the exact same error occurs.

I had pip version 1.5.6 previously and just updated to 9.0.1 via advice from comments below. It hasn't yet fixed the issues (yet).

I've tried `sudo chown -R $USER /Library/Python/2.7` thinking it may have been a permission problem and I also did mess around with `brew install pkg-config` and `brew install freetype` to no avail.

Does anyone have any ideas how to fix this?

Edit: No it's not a virtual environment, it's on my Mac off terminal with default install locations with pip and python.

Comment: Are you using a virtual environment? Try VirtualEnv to have a fresh environment https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/

Comment: No I'm not currently using a virtual environment, I'll take a look at this.

Comment: It might be an issue with pip, that it is outdated enough that it can handle a new package style/command that made its way into mpl2's `setup.py`. Hard to say though, with the limited traceback. Any chance you could add a few more lines that come before the current ones (not all, but 10-20, that would show clearer where the error originates)?

Comment: There you go, updated to include all lines above the original error code I posted.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solved by installing anaconda. It comes with the latest version of matplotlib. I recommend anyone else to do this as well.

Answer (score 0):

Too long for a comment, hope it helps anyway.

From the line `File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in main`, it looks like Evert is right and that your pip is updated itself (it is probably the one that came with the system). Type `pip --version` to confirm (and copy-paste the result to your question).

If that is the case (pip , I suggest that you update by 1. adding `~/.local/bin` to the PATH https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_%28variable%29 environment variable via the file `~/.bash_profile` 2. restart the terminal and 3. issue `pip install -U --user pip setuptools`. Check that `which pip` returns `~/.local/bin/pip`.

Then uninstall the system-wide installed matplotlib (installing with pip in `/Library` will cause trouble) and try `pip install -U --user matplotlib`.

Comment: I checked my pip version, and it's 1.5.6, I just updated it to 9.0.1, but trying to update matplotlib, still the same error. I'll try everything you suggested above and will get back to you, cheers.

Comment: I just tried uninstalling using pip uninstall matplotlib but it doesn't seem happy with it. Gives exact same error as above. Is there a better way to install?

Comment: What is the output of `which pip`? Also, you might need (be careful here, this is your responsibility) to go in the directory where matplotlib is installed, `cd /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages` and remove all previous traces of matplotlib `rm -r matplotlib*` (caution: no space between matplotlib and the star, do first `ls matplotlib*`, go up one step in your terminal history (up arrow) and replace the ls by `rm -r`).

Comment: `which pip` returns `/usr/local/bin/pip`

Comment: what is the output of `pip --version`, of `echo $PATH`?

Comment: Oddly enough in `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages` there is no matplotlib file...

Comment: `pip --version` returns
`pip 9.0.1 from /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)`

Comment: `ls /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages`?

Comment: `ls /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages` shows matplotlib, yes, it's there. Shall I remove it?

Comment: yes. overall the ideal situtation is when, beyond the base system, you have only one copy of the pip-installed packages that is in `~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/` (+ extra virtualenvs if you want), including pip, matplotlib, numpy, etc. Also, a single "bin" location with the pip-installed executables  (i.e. `~/.local/bin`, for instance).

Comment: so ive deleted it, but `pip list | grep matplotlib` still shows that 1.3.1 is installed? Should I try to install again? This makes very little sense to me but I imagine after deleting I shouldnt be able to use matplotlib anymore but i still can...

Comment: The location of matplotlib can be found by running `python -c 'import matplotlib ; print matplotlib.__file__`. Uninstall this one also